# Where to find precompiled Qt for macOS with -static option?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'am trying to compile qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar.gz for static linking on macOS 10.12.4 using this options:
./configure -opensource -confirm-license -release -static -ssl -openssl-linked -opengl -nomake examples -prefix /Developer/Qt -recheck-all

The compilation of Qt finishes ok. But when I compile my application with this static Qt then compiler says me this:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "minimal"
>
> in "".
>
> Available platform plugins are: cocoa.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Why? Did I build Qt wrongly?

I think I need a precompiled -static Qt package with full support of everything. Where can I find it?

If such does not exist then may be a list of proper configure parameters and libraries (like icu and openssl) will help me.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're not compiling your application with the Qt version you think you are.

The only way to specify what version of Qt to use in a qmake project is to *directly invoke the `qmake` of the Qt version you intend to use*. There is a 1:1 relationship between a `qmake` binary and a Qt installtion.

> I think I need a precompiled -static Qt package with full support of everything.

Whoever would provide such a precompiled version for you would do exactly what you did to compile yours.